# Не устанавливается Electron JS

Tags: npm, electron

Всем привет, решил сделать веб приложение на основе Electron JS. Первым делом я решил ознакомится с [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start#electron-quick-start).

Но тут у меня возникла проблема при установке через npm.

Скачал [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start#electron-quick-start), перешёл в директорию
D:\MyProject\MyPrograms\electron-quick-start-master>
после этого по инструкции ввёл в терминале

```
npm install
```

и

```
npm start
```

И получил следующее сообщение

> D:\MyProject\MyPrograms\electron-quick-start-master>npm install
>
> > electron@2.0.0 postinstall D:\MyProject\MyPrograms\electron-quick-start-master\node_mo
> >     dules\electron
> >     node install.js
>
> ... and 1 more
>   D:\MyProject\MyPrograms\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\electron\install.js:47
>   throw err   ^
>
> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
>       at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1055:34)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:635:8) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! electron@2.0.0 postinstall: `node
>   install.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   electron@2.0.0 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging out put above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\German\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-21T14_29_05_756Z-de
>   bug.log

Вот логи

[2018-06-21T14_29_05_756Z-debug.txt](https://github.com/HermanQuaint/Error-log/blob/master/2018-06-21T14_29_05_756Z-debug.txt)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm init --yes  
$ npm i electron
```

Далее в `package.json` ищешь `"scripts"` и там `"test"` меняешь на:

```
"start": "electron ."
```

Теперь уже можно:

```
$ npm start
```

Comment: После ввода в терминале "npm i", та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Я дал решение без electron-quick-start. Создай на диске `C` папку. Открой эту папку с помощью консоли, далее следуй инструкциям, данным в моём ответе. Главное, что бы в `package.json` `"main"` совпадал со скоиптом, создающим окно electron. Вот пример моего приложения на electron: [github](https://github.com/Don2Quixote/Saper). Опирайся на это. Обрати внимание на `package.json` в моём примере, проанализируй, что там написано, какие скрипты с его помощью вызываются. Ты сможешь это понять.